# Lock displayed frame interval to time

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, graph-editor, dopesheet, timeline

As you can see in image below, I'm using Blender for Video Editing, displaying vse, timeline, dopesheet and graph editor. I have locked time in  all of the windows. You can see the green line set in the same frame at each one of them... Excepting of the timeline, which is set to a different frames interval. If I press play, the line will "come out" of my dopesheet and graph editor, and I will have to scroll to it's new location, in order to modifying what I see. I wonder if there's any way to lock window's displayed frames interval to time, so they kinda move allthogether with the green time cursor.

Thanks!

[image: video editing example image]

Comment: I asked for this some years ago and it could not be implemented. You can try hovering in the window you want to zoom and press the period key ( . ). This will snap the view to the play head (green line)

Comment: Thanks @3pointedit 
Pressing period key worked well on vse and graph editor. It worked neither on the timeline nor on the dopesheet. It makes workflow a bit smoother, thougt!